# SQL foreach using table rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two Access tables. One table (table1) has a unique field, MyID and another table (table2) has several rows with MyID and another column, Data. I'd like to write an SQL statement that is similar to a foreach where all the values for MyID are selected and averaged from table2's Data and then updated in the MyID row under another field, Avg.

```
**Table1**
MyID
ID1
ID2
ID3  

**Table2**
MyID   Data   Mon
ID2    10     Jan
ID2    20     Feb
ID1    10     Jan
ID3    30     Mar
ID1    30     Mar
```

Expecting results like:

```
**Table1**
MyID    Avg
ID1     20
ID2     15
ID3     30
```

Maybe there's a better way to do this in SQL, but don't currently know.

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE  table1
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT Data1, AVG(columnName) avgCol
            FROM table2
            GROUP BY Data1
        ) b ON table1.MyID = b.Data
SET     table1.avgColumnName = b.avgCol
```

- [MS Access update with join](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/update2.php)

Comment: I get the error message: The MS Office Access db engine can't find the object 'AVG(Data) avgCol'.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick in MS Access as a query but not updating into a table.

```
SELECT Table2.[MyID], Avg(Table2.[Data]) AS [AVG]
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Table2.[MyID]
```