# Populating a table using modified data from a different one. (SQL)

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL so I'm sorry if this is a simple problem. Here's the most bare-bones version of it (which seems very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399597/sql-foreach-using-table-rows)):

I have two tables, Table1 and Table2. Table1 has two string columns called 'ID' and 'DATA', and Table2 has a 'UID' column and a 'FATDATA' column. The ids in Table2 are all unique but not in Table1, and the IDs in Table1 are assumed appear as UIDs in Table2.

```
**Table1**
ID    DATA   OTHERSTUFF
id1          ...
id1          ...
id2          ...
id2          ...
id3          ...

**Table2**
UID   FATDATA               MORESTUFF
id1   'adsf<data1>asdgas'   ...
id2   'hrhdfh<data2>sdh'    ...
id3   'adhfdh<data3>adf'    ...
```

What I need to do is populate the DATA column of Table1 using the FATDATA from Table2. Specifically, for each row in Table1 I need to take its ID, look up the unique corresponding row in Table2, and then trim down its FATDATA value with a specific procedure and store the result in the row in Table1.

The end result should be

```
**Table1**
ID    DATA      OTHERSTUFF
id1   'data1'   ...
id1   'data1'   ... 
id2   'data2'   ...
id2   'data2'   ...
id3   'data3'   ...
```

Can I do something like John Woo's solution to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399597/sql-foreach-using-table-rows) mentioned at the start, except with my own "TRIM(str)" function instead of "AVG(intCol)"? Again I'm still new to SQL so I'm having trouble even understanding what his code is doing.

Answer (score 2):

```
update Table1 set DATA = (select FATDATA from Table2 where UID = Table1.ID)
where exists (select FATDATA from Table2 where UID = Table1.ID)
```

Comment: I almost have your solution working, but in my specific case I'm getting a "Column not found error". My id's are not actually equal, but I'm looking for one contained in the other, and only if FATADATA has a certain form. My actual call looks more like 
update Table1 set DATA = (
    select MyStringTrimmer(FATDATA) from Table2
    where FATADATA like '%Ref.%' and locate(Table1.ID, Table2.UID) > 0); 
It says "Column DATA cannot be null" but the column exists. I've used similar syntax in a select call without any issue. Maybe you can see a mistake.

Comment: @you It sounds like the subquery doesn't find a match and returns a `null`. You'll also have to be careful that it doesn't return *more than one* value too.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try to work out some queries which find the ID's without any matches and the ID's with multiple matches. It may be due to user error when they populated the databases.

Comment: @you Ok. Btw, easy to find the ones that don't match: `select * from Table1 where not exists (select 1 from Table2 where <insert your conditions here>)`

Comment: I think I've managed to compile a list of those IDs which either do not match to a UID, or that match multiple. I ran my query for those IDs which are not in this list, and I still get a "Column cannot be null" error, so there might still be other problems with it.

Comment: @you You can certainly add a `where` clause to filter out the bad ones. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a joined `UPDATE`. You can invoke a `FUNCTION` using the following syntax :

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.otherstuff = YourFunction(t2.fatdata)
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.uid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a join, so something like

```
update a
set Data = b.FATDATA
from Table1 a
join Table2 b
on a.ID = b.UID
```

In your set rather than just assign to b.FATDATA you'd do your trim functions or whatever you need to get the actual value you want to assign.

Comment: This is not valid MySQL syntax.

Comment: Oh. Could be. It was also tagged SQL Server so I just tested in it.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't realize SQL Server was a separate thing. I'll removed the tag

Answer (score 0):

I was beat to the punch. I recommend reading up on joins and getting very good at them. you will use joins all the time in SQL.

[W3School Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)